# Using the Vocmax library and get_weather_data function but trying to find data file that takes minutes to generate, instantly causing issues

Tags: python, pandas

I am having issues with the vocmax library in python. The documentation says the function should take around 3 minutes per latitude and longitude coordinate. However, it is trying to read the `df_iter` being generated by `vocmax main.py` function within seconds, causing it to fail since the `dataframe` has not been gotten from the api yet.

Here is my python code:

```
weather, info = vocmax.get_weather_data(lat,lon,api_key=api_key)
```

Here is my error

```
cached_weather_data\*_45.136_-92.307.npz
Downloading weather data and saving to "cached_weather_data" ...
  0%|                                                                                                                     | 0/21 [00:00<?, ?it/s]C:\Users\FS126969\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pvlib\iotools\psm3.py:359: pvlibDeprecationWarning: PSM3 variable names will be renamed to pvlib conventions by default starting in pvlib 0.11.0. Specify map_variables=True to enable that behavior now, or specify map_variables=False to hide this warning.
  warnings.warn(
  0%|                                                                                                                     | 0/21 [00:03<?, ?it/s] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\FS126969\Downloads\PVTools_weather_file.py", line 244, in <module>
    weather, info = vocmax.get_weather_data(lat, lon,
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\FS126969\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\vocmax\main.py", line 279, in get_weather_data
    year_iter = str(df_iter['Year'][0])
                    ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'Year'
```

I've changed the `api_key` to see if that was the issue, but it detects when the `api_key` is wrong. I have also tried the coordinates that says are samples and dont need to be downloaded, but get the same error. If anyone has any experience or suggestions on this, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the issue I was having above.

If you are referring to the get_weather_data function, there is a small error in the source code that needs to be fixed. If you have git cloned the vocmax repo, you should be able to right click in your script where you have vocmax.get_weather_data(lat,lon,api_key) and select "Go to definition". This will open up the vocmax main.py script where the error is. In vocmax main.py, get_weather_data is defined on line 107. The error is in the function definition on line 233, that should be:

```
 info_iter, df_iter = get_psm3(
        latitude=lat,
        longitude=lon,
        api_key=api_key,
        email=email,
        names=year,
        interval=30,
        leap_day=False,
        full_name=full_name,
        affiliation=affiliation,
        timeout=30)
```

The change is very simple. All you must do is flip info_iter and df_iter like so:

```
   df_iter, info_iter = get_psm3(
        latitude=lat,
        longitude=lon,
        api_key=api_key,
        email=email,
        names=year,
        interval=30,
        leap_day=False,
        full_name=full_name,
        affiliation=affiliation,
        timeout=30)
```

info_iter is a dictionary for the backend steps, and df_iter is the data frame you are downloading. The variable are just swapped in the source code, but flipping them should fix your issue.

I hope this helps!